# Grails Order By Not Working

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, sql-order-by, grails-orm

I have a Grails query that has an order by clause, but when the results come back they are not ordered by that field. If I run the same query in the database it works correctly.

```
String sql = "select child From Affiliation a join a.childrenPhases cp join cp.affiliation child where a = :affiliation and child.type = '${TYPE_CONFERENCE}' order by a.name asc"
        return  executeQuery(sql, [affiliation: this])
```

`name` off of `a` is a hibernate formula field. Could this have to do with it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to troubleshoot a problem like this is to dump the SQL generated by hibernate.  Add the following to your DataSource.groovy:

```
loggingSql = true
```